# Improve this schematic to guarantee 12V and 70 mA in the fan

Tags: mosfet-driver, fan

I would like to learn how to correctly design a circuit to drive a fan using a mosfet and a battery as a power source. These are the characteristics:

**FAN**

- Model: SPDL8025S
- Rated Voltage: 12V
- Operating Voltage Range: 6-13.8V
- Rated Current: 70mA

**MOSFET**

In principle, now I only have these two N-Mosfet to test the circuit:

- [IRF730](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91047/91047.pdf)
- [IRF540N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf540n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e396cb199f)

**BATTERY**

- Nominal Voltage: 14.8v
- Voltage at end of Discharge: 12v
- Charging Voltage: 16.8v

The schematic that I have thought to use is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGf62y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**QUESTION**

Because the range of the battery is between 12-16.8V. What would have to change in the schematic to guarantee (approximately) 12V and 70 mA in the fan?

Comment: What is more important, price or accuracy/stability/...?

Comment: In principle, high stability or precision is not required. Also, the price is not a problem either because it is a prototype

Comment: _In principle, now I only have these two P-Mosfet to test the circuit_ Both are N-channel.

Comment: Are you afraid of overvoltage? Read the datasheet for the fan, it's not 12.0 V +- 0%, but 16.8 V may still be outside of it's maximum rating. A regulator perhaps.

Comment: @winny Sorry. it's been a lapse. Effectively they are channel N. Edited

Comment: Limit voltage to 12V.  The fan is rated to draw 70mA when operated on 12V.  Current limiting is only needed if you have reason to fear the it will draw more than the rated current - or when drawing more than 70mA would cause a catastrophe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a low current of 70mA, a simple lineair voltage regulator like the 78L12 could be used.

In the worst-case scenario (+VBAT = 16.8V ) the power dissipated by the regulator would be: ((16.8V-12V)*0.070A)+(16.8V * 0.0045A) = 0.412W. 
This means that the small TO-92 package (Pmax = 0.600W) could be used.

At at thermal resistance of 180°C/W (package to still air)  0.412W would result in a temperature of 74°C. Hot enough to burn your fingers. So maybe place the voltage regulator near the fan. :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk67fp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Principle shown here is fine but keep in mind that 7812 has 3 V dropout voltage, so when your battery is 12 V, you may have as low as 9 V on your fan. There are low dropout alternatives to 7812.

Comment: The 78L12 has a dropout of around 2V. The fan in question has a range of 6 - 13.8V. So in either situation, the fan operates within specification. The only side-effect is that the fan could run a bit slower when the battery is near dead.

Comment: Oh! But I would still go for a low dropout LDO. 78xx is ancient.

Answer (score 2):

If battery life is a important issue, then I'd PWM the fan to get about 12 V average across it.

One way to do that is to use a low end microcontroller with a A/D and PWM module.  Measure the battery voltage, and set the PWM duty cycle open loop.

Duty cycle = (12 V)/V<sub>batt</sub>

That should result in close enough to 12 V across the fan, and it won't burn up battery power as heat in a linear regulator.

On another issue, the 1N4007 is inappropriate here.  Use a Schottky.  It will be more efficient due to lower on voltage, and will have effectively instantaneous reverse recovery in this application.  The 1N4007 is quite slow, and will result in significant shoot thru at the start of each PWM pulse.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and correction of the diode for operation by PWM. In principle the fan only works with the battery when there is no power supply and for a short time